# Graphics card help for my current desktop?

Tags: graphics-cards, pc

I currently have a PC with the following hardware:

- CPU - Intel 6600K.
- Motherboard: Asus Maximums VIII Ranger.
- Case: Noctis 450.
- Also, monitor: Dell U2414H, 1080p.

I am currently using integrated graphics but later plan on buying a descrete graphics card. I watch HD movies,  which currently is not smooth at all, mainly program in Android Studio and do some video editing in Sony Vegas Pro.

Can any recommend a graphics card no more than £200? Thanks  in advance.

Comment: Something is wrong, as your 6600K's Intel 530 integrated graphics should be PLENTY powerful for HD movies. try updating the drivers for that; get them from the intel support website. https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/88345/Intel-HD-Graphics-530-for-6th-Generation-Intel-Core-Processors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would highly recommend and AMD RX 480 - 4GB model. That is less than 200 Euros i believe. If you save a big more you could get the 8GB model, given if you are just watching HD movies and rendering videos than the 4GB model should be perfect for you use cases!

Plus, Sony Vegas does get Accelerated Graphics support from AMD Graphics Cards, so you will be able to render video faster!

Answer (score 1):

The 480 is not a bad choice for that rig especially that the pc is not meant for heavy gaming. But if you wanted a little more performance you could also go Nvidia and get the new GTX 1060 which performs just a littlebit better than the 480 or if you wanted outstanding performance for the same ~$250 price point you could also get the GTX 970 which would be a really good pair for your CPU, but keep in mind, that is now a generation behind the latest GPUs from Nvidia. Of course all of the aforesaid GPUs offer very high end performace for editing and I don't think you would regret getting either one of them.